# Let consider a square $10$x$10$ and write in the every unit square the numbers from $1$ to $100$

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, chessboard

Let   consider   a  square $10\times 10$   and  write  in  the   every   unit  square    the   numbers   from  $1$  to  $100$   such  that   every  two   consecutive  numbers  are  in   squares   which  has  a  common edge.  Then  there  are  two  perfect  squares   on  the  same line  or  column. Can  you   give  me  an  hint? How  to  start?

Comment: Are you sure this is guaranteed to be true? It's possible to avoid when you write the numbers $1, 2, \dots, 16$ in a $4\times 4$ square.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's because $4/2$ is even. Here, $10/2$ is odd. :)

Comment: Recommendation concerning editing:  Phrases such as "Let consider...", while ungrammatical, are also vacuous and fluff.  Unneeded.  Phrases such as "Can you give me a hint?" are also useless.  Of *course* we know you're asking for help... that is why you're here.  Using raw text ("10x10") when this is a mathematics site and proper typography can be used ("$10 \times 10$"... with a proper operation sign instead of an English letter) should be used.  Also "which has a common edge" is ungrammatical; any "editor" who doesn't fix this, and all the remaining errors, is doing this site a disservice.

Comment: Suggested revision:  "Prove that if every integer $1 \to 100$ is placed in a different unit cell of a $10 \times 10$ grid, where the cells for successive integers share an edge, then there must be two perfect squares in a row or column."  So much clearer, focused, and grammatical while avoiding fluff.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Do not forget that English is not a native language for many users.

Comment: Hint: Starting from $0$ the perfect squares are generated by adding consecutive odd numbers. For example, $1^2 = 0+1$, $2^2=1+3$, $3^2=4+5$, etc.

Comment: @user.  Of *course* English is not the native language for many users, such as rafa.  Of *course*!  That is why we help them clarify their thoughts, and perhaps learn a bit about English along the way.  (See my analysis below.)

Comment: IMHO "Can you give me a hint? How to start?" is **very** useful.  It says the OP prefers a hint to a full solution revealed.

Comment: Giving a good hint is definitely an art. You not only have to have the problem solved in your head but you want to give something useful to the person asking so they can get through the crux of the problem.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this problem hasn't received more attention. It is a fun one....

Answer (score 2):

We note the following:

1. Write the coordinates of $k$ as $(i_k,j_k)$, where $i_k$ is the column that $k$ is in; $i_k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 10\}$; and $j_k$ is the row that $k$ is in; $j_k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 10\}$. Then if $i_k+j_k$ is even, then $i_{k+1} + j_{k+1}$ must be odd, for each $k=1,2,\ldots, 99$.
2. If $i_{k^2} + j_{k^2}$ is even, then $i_{(k+1)^2} + j_{(k+1)^2}$ must be odd, as $(k+1)^2-k^2$ is an odd integer, for each $k=1,2,\ldots, 9$.
3. We call a square $k^2$ *even-even* if $i_{k^2}$ and $j_{k^2}$ are both even. 
   and we call a square $k^2$ *odd-odd* if $i_{k^2}$ and $j_{k^2}$ are both odd. We call a square *mixed* otherwise. Then if $k^2$ is odd-odd or even-even, then $(k+1)^2$ must be mixed.

So from 3 we have the following:

> 4. Precisely 5 squares are mixed and precisely 5 squares that are either even-even or odd-odd.

But this is impossible unless a row or column has at least 2 squares:

> Indeed: Either at least 3 of the squares $k^2; k=1,2,\ldots, 10$; are even-even, or at least 3 of the squares are odd-odd. LEt us assume that 3 of the squares are even-even. Then if every row and column has exactly one square, then of the 5 mixed squares, only 2 can be in an even column (as 3 of the even columns were already taken by the 3 even-evens and so there are only 2 even columns left). And likewise, only 2 can be in an even row. But this implies that at least one (i.e. $5-2-2$) of the 5 mixed squares is odd-odd after all, which contradicts 4. above. [The likewise holds by the same line of reasoning holds if 3 of the squares are odd-odd.]

Answer (score 2):

Here are several successively more revealing hints, hidden behind spoilers in case you want to try the problem after only reading one or two.

**Hint 1:**

Color your $10\times 10$ board like a checkerboard. What can you say about the colors of the squares containing perfect squares?

More specifically:

> How does the color of square $1$ compare to that of $4$? And how does $4$ compare to that of $9$? Etc.

**Hint 2:**

> In general, show that for any $10$ squares in pairwise different rows and columns, an even number of these squares must be black.
>
>   Assuming that a path where the perfect squares are in different rows and columns exists, combine this fact with the conclusion of Hint $1$ to get a contradiction.

**Hint 3:**

> This goes into more detail about how to prove the first sentence of Hint $2$.
>
>  Suppose there are $10$ squares in pairwise different rows and columns. A square in row $i$ and column $j$ is black if and only if $i+j$ is even.
>
>  Suppose square in row $i$ is in column $\pi_i$, where $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i+\pi_i)$ is equal in parity to the number of black squares, so you need to prove this summation is even.

Comment: You may need to elaborate more. Isn't $\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i+\pi_i) = 2 \times 55$ which is even? Meanwhile, so what if an even number of squares are black?

Comment: OK I do see it now....nice

Comment: Actually RE Hint 1 you could say a little bit more...it wasn't clear to me. Maybe "what can you say about the number of squares on black and the number of squares on white" and even put a subhint such as "if $i^2$ is on white then $(i+1)^2$ is on ...."

Comment: @Mike are you the same Mike who posted the other answer?  This Hint 1 is precisely that answer's #4.  :)

Comment: @antkam I see it now but it took me a good minute

Comment: BTW @MikeEarnest I love your direct approach in Hint 3.  I did it a more roundabout way: The main diagonal has $10$ black squares.  Every permutation can be made by a series of transpositions.  And every transposition will change the number of black squares by <spoiler removed> :)

Comment: @Mike I take your point, I've added a sub hint. I've deleted some of my earlier comments to prevent spoilers. I think that  "I see it now but it took me a good minute" is perfect reaction to a hint!

Comment: @MikeEarnest good edits!